# How To Open New Activity And View The Details When We Click RecyclerView Items

Tags: android-activity, android-recyclerview, onitemclicklistener

**How to Open New Activity When We Click Recycler View Items And Show The Item Data In New Activity**

**MainActivity.java:** This is My MainActivity java class

```
package com.codinginflow.firebaseui_firestoreexample;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.support.v7.widget.helper.ItemTouchHelper;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.firebase.ui.firestore.FirestoreRecyclerOptions;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.CollectionReference;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.Query;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    private CollectionReference notebookRef = db.collection("Notebook");

    private NoteAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        FloatingActionButton buttonAddNote = findViewById(R.id.button_add_note);
        buttonAddNote.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, NewNoteActivity.class));
            }
        });

        setUpRecyclerView();
    }

    private void setUpRecyclerView() {
        Query query = notebookRef.orderBy("priority", Query.Direction.DESCENDING);

        FirestoreRecyclerOptions<Note> options = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<Note>()
                .setQuery(query, Note.class)
                .build();

        adapter = new NoteAdapter(options);

        RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        new ItemTouchHelper(new ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(0,
                ItemTouchHelper.LEFT | ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT) {
            @Override
            public boolean onMove(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public void onSwiped(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {
                adapter.deleteItem(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition());
            }
        }).attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView);

        adapter.setOnItemClickListener(new NoteAdapter.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot, int position) {
                Note note = documentSnapshot.toObject(Note.class);
                String id = documentSnapshot.getId();
                String path = documentSnapshot.getReference().getPath();
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                        "Position: " + position + " ID: " + id, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        adapter.startListening();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        adapter.stopListening();
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**: This Is My Activity Main Layout.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/button_add_note"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_add" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**note_item.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="#FFFFE8">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="8dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_view_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@id/text_view_priority"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:text="Title"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_view_priority"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:text="1"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_view_description"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_below="@id/text_view_title"
            android:text="Description" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

**Note.java:**

```
 package com.codinginflow.firebaseui_firestoreexample;

public class Note {
    private String title;
    private String description;
    private int priority;

    public Note() {
        //empty constructor needed
    }

    public Note(String title, String description, int priority) {
        this.title = title;
        this.description = description;
        this.priority = priority;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public int getPriority() {
        return priority;
    }
}
```

**NoteAdapter.java:**

```
 package com.codinginflow.firebaseui_firestoreexample;

import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.firebase.ui.firestore.FirestoreRecyclerAdapter;
import com.firebase.ui.firestore.FirestoreRecyclerOptions;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot;

public class NoteAdapter extends FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<Note, NoteAdapter.NoteHolder> {
    private OnItemClickListener listener;

    public NoteAdapter(@NonNull FirestoreRecyclerOptions<Note> options) {
        super(options);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull NoteHolder holder, int position, @NonNull Note model) {
        holder.textViewTitle.setText(model.getTitle());
        holder.textViewDescription.setText(model.getDescription());
        holder.textViewPriority.setText(String.valueOf(model.getPriority()));
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public NoteHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.note_item,
                parent, false);
        return new NoteHolder(v);
    }

    public void deleteItem(int position) {
        getSnapshots().getSnapshot(position).getReference().delete();
    }

    class NoteHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView textViewTitle;
        TextView textViewDescription;
        TextView textViewPriority;

        public NoteHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            textViewTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_view_title);
            textViewDescription = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_view_description);
            textViewPriority = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_view_priority);

            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    int position = getAdapterPosition();
                    if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION && listener != null) {
                        listener.onItemClick(getSnapshots().getSnapshot(position), position);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }

    public interface OnItemClickListener {
        void onItemClick(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot, int position);
    }

    public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
    }
}
```

**ActivityDetail.java:** Here Is My Second Activity Detail.java And I want to Open Full Details Of An Item In This Activity

```
 package com.codinginflow.firebaseui_firestoreexample;


import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;


public class ActivityDeatail extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail);
    }
}
```

**activiy_detail.xml:**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ActivityDetail">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/D_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.084" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/D_description"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/D_title"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.002" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/D_priority"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to open detailActivity bu clicking on each item of your recyclerView you can use of Intent to approach that. Something like this in your `itemView.setOnClickListener`

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext() , DetailActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("Your_key" , 
     yourList.get(view.getVerticalScrollbarPosition()))
    view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
```

And in your DetailActivity get your data like this:

```
YourModel model = getIntent().getSerializableExtra("Your_key");
```

Do not forget to `Serialized` your Model.

Comment: Please Tellll Me In ActivityDetail.java

Comment: I want to open detailActivity by clicking on each item of your recyclerView And View The Content Of Item

Comment: What Is Key In Both Activities

Comment: you have to define a string for your data that you want to pass to your activity and with that key, you can get your data in your activity